# C: Struct syntax Linked Lists

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Is the following

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

the only way one can define a `struct` so that one needn't write out `struct` inside
of the rest of the program when using it?

I.e. by the above `struct` the following works just fine:

```
node* head = NULL;
```

But, is there another way to express the same `struct` that is generally considered better?

Comment: Explain: what do you mean by *better* ?

Comment: Less verbose without impacting comprehension negatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You could also do:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node node;
```

'Better' isn't really a qualifier that can be applied to these; to my knowledge there is no advantage to one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! You're spot on. In C++ this isn't necessary, but in C some people (Linux kernel for example) where they prefer leaving things as structs ([see here](https://github.com/mirrors/linux/blob/master/include/net/af_unix.h#L23))

Comment: Thank you, that's an interesting link you've provided. Do you know why they do this?

Comment: here's the master himself explaining why: http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html